# How to empty an array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

Yesterday I ask a question about json

Link: [How to return an array from jQuery ajax success function and use it in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787159/how-to-return-an-array-from-jquery-ajax-success-function-and-use-it-in-a-loop/9788845#9788845)

And one of the answers was this

```
setInterval(updateTimestamps,30000);
var ids = new Array();

function updateTimestamps(){
    $(".timestamp").each(function(i){
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.id = $(this).attr("postID");
    obj.timestamp = $(this).attr("postdate");
        ids.push(obj);
    }

    $.post("http://site.com/ajax/humanTime.php", {"time": ids}, function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#" + data[i].id).html(data[i].content);
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

The problem with this script is that the data is dublicated

The first time when this is executed is something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26629
            [timestamp] => 1332273712
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26628
            [timestamp] => 1332243526
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26627
            [timestamp] => 1332237777


)
```

And the second time is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26629
            [timestamp] => 1332273712
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26628
            [timestamp] => 1332243526
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26627
            [timestamp] => 1332237777
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26629
            [timestamp] => 1332273712
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26628
            [timestamp] => 1332243526
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26627
            [timestamp] => 1332237777
        )

)
```

I try with var ids= Array(); , vas ids = []; but that dosent work

Comment: Did you check what the PHP script itself returns ?

Answer (score 3):

Set `ids = []` before you start pushing *new* items. Here is your code, re-factored:

```
var ids;

function updateTimestamps() {
    ids = []; // <-- the answer
    $(".timestamp").each(function(i) {
        ids.push({
            id: $(this).attr("postID"),
            timestamp: $(this).attr("postdate")
        });
    });
    $.post("http://site.com/ajax/humanTime.php", {"time": ids}, function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#" + data[i].id).html(data[i].content);
        }
    }, "json");
}

setInterval(updateTimestamps, 30000);​
```

Answer (score 3):

A short way to reset an array: `ids.length = 0;`. So

```
function updateTimestamps(){
  ids.length = 0;
  // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var ids;

function updateTimestamps(){
  ids = [];
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

After

```
function updateTimestamps(){
```

Add

```
ids = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(updateTimestamps,30000);

function updateTimestamps(){
    var ids = []; // put it here

    $(".timestamp").each(function(i){
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = $(this).attr("postID");
    obj.timestamp = $(this).attr("postdate");
        ids.push(obj);
    }

    $.post("http://site.com/ajax/humanTime.php", {"time": ids}, function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#" + data[i].id).html(data[i].content);
        }
    }, "json");
}
```